# How can I get screenshot real device in Intellj?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Is somebody using intellj in android projects here? I want to get screenshot realdevice in debug mode my android projects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start DDMS from the terminal or command line. Select the device and go to Devices -> Screen Capture

DDMS is in the tools directory in the Android SDK installation path.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about in IntelliJ but outside of Eclipse you can still take screenshots. Use the SDK.

```
 /path/to/android-sdk/tools/
```

and open

```
 ddms
```

Path:

[image]

You can then take screenshots:

[image: Screenshots with DDMS]

Reference:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/index.html#tips

Comment: I know in eclipse but i can not find a tab about screenshot in intellj?

Comment: @DeyguK that's what I'm saying you can't in IntelliJ, the above shows you how to do it from the SDK Tool **not eclipse**